# Encog compiling error

Tags: java, maven, encog

I am using Windows 7 to compile Encog using Maven. When attempting to perform the `mvn package` command I receive the following error:

```
C:\Users\294365\Desktop\Encog\encog-java-core-3.3>mvn package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/sonatype/oss/oss-parent/5/oss-parent-5.pom
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for org.encog:encog-core:3.3.0: Could not transfer 
artifact org.sonatype.oss:oss-parent:pom:5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): 
Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/23.235.39.215] failed: 
Connection refused: connect and 'parent.relativePath'
points at wrong local POM @ line 64, column 10
@
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project org.encog:encog-core:3.3.0 (C:\Users\294365\Desktop\Encog\
encog-java-core-3.3\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for org.encog:encog-core:3.3.0: Could not
transfer artifact org.sonatype.oss:oss-parent:pom:5 from/to central (https://rep
o.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apa
che.org/23.235.39.215] failed: Connection refused: connect and 'parent.relativePath' 
points at wrong local POM @ line 64, column 10 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

My interpretation of this is that it is trying to reach out to the web address mentioned in the error to grab the parent POM file and bring it back. My work computer, which I am using for the project, is controlled relatively strictly for what can go in and out. For instance IE is disabled and cannot be used to reach the outside. I am wondering if this is the reason for the error, but I am not sure. I took the oss-parent:pom:5 file and saved it as .xml in my source files and attempted to redirect the encog POM by adding a relativePath shown below:

```
<parent>
<groupId>org.sonatype.oss</groupId>
<artifactId>oss-parent</artifactId>
<version>5</version>
<relativePath>C:\Users\294365\Desktop\Encog\encog-java-core-3.3\org_sonatype_oss_ossparent_pom_5</relativePath>
</parent>
```

This resulted in the exact same error as above.

Comment: Are you really building with Maven 2? Please post the Maven and JDK version you are using.

Comment: The problem is exactly based on what you said. `failed: 
Connection refused: connect and `. So configuration for a proxy needed if you have one ...

Comment: Apache Maven 3.3.3 Java Version 1.8.0_51. 

How do I go out attempting configuration for a proxy? Where/what code do I implement?